# When update an accordion It doesn't hold the open/closed tab

Tags: html, primefaces, xhtml, accordion

I have a big problem with Primefaces accordion.
I have an outputPanel with an header and an accordion with 2 tabs.
If I close the first tab and change a field in the second tab, it open the first tab and close the second. How can I keep the status of the tabs?

This is a simple example:

```
<p:outputPanel id="content">
    <p:outputPanel id="header" />

    <p:accordionPanel multiple="true">
        <p:tab title="firstTab">
            <p:panel>
                <p:inputText id="firstInput" value="firstInput">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="content" />
                </p:inputText>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
        <p:tab title="secondTab">
            <p:panel>
                <p:inputText id="secondInput" value="secondInput">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="content" />
                </p:inputText>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>
    </p:accordionPanel>     

</p:outputPanel>
```

How can i resolve it? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

AccordionPanel has an attribute called activeIndex, you could set this attribute from your MB so it doesn´t change after an update. See for instance https://www.primefaces.org/docs/vdl/6.1/core/primefaces-p/accordionPanel.html

Comment: Hi, I've noticed that attribute, but everytime I open/close a tab I need to update that attribute manually. In my real case I've 6 accordions and a totale of 15 tabs, so it's a little hard. Is there another way?

Comment: What do you mean manually? maybe the ajax event tabChange or tabClose can help

Comment: Yes, I mean using event tabChange and tabClose. When I load the page or update the panel I have activeIndex = (0). Then if I close the first tab I need to update the index to () and If I open the second tab, activeIndex should be (1). But I can do this only with a Java method for every tab and every event. e.g. If I close the first tab, remove 0 from active index, if I open it add 0, if I close the second tab remove 1 and if I open it add 1. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: The answer of cagatay.civici may help you 
    https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=20153

Answer (score 0):

Based on cagatay civici's answer provided in the [link](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?t=20153) by @Christian I created a simple example, because it was not working out of the box for me.

The *example.xthml*:

```
<h:form styleClass="accordionForm">
    <p:accordionPanel multiple="true"
        activeIndex="#{sessionBean.activeTabs}">

        <p:ajax event="tabChange" />
        <p:ajax event="tabClose" />
        
        <p:tab title="Tab1">
            <p:panel>
                <p:inputText id="firstInput" value="firstInput">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="@(.accordionForm)" />
                </p:inputText>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

        <p:tab title="Tab2">
            <p:panel>
                <p:inputText id="secondInput" value="secondInput">
                    <p:ajax event="change" update="@(.accordionForm)" />
                </p:inputText>
            </p:panel>
        </p:tab>

    </p:accordionPanel>
</h:form>
```

The *sessionBean.java*:

```
@Named("sessionBean")
@SessionScoped
public class SessionBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String activeTabs = "";

    public String getActiveTabs() {
        return activeTabs;
    }

    public void setActiveTabs(String activeTabs) {
        this.activeTabs = activeTabs;
    }
}
```

Explanation:

The two `p:ajax` tags trigger a POST request if a tab is either opened ("tabChange") or closed ("tabClosed"), since this is the default action for the accordionPanel. Hence, I wrapped the `p:accordionPanel` with an `h:form`. If you inspect your network traffic you can see how the list of active tabs is sent to the server.

Bear in mind that I update the surrounding form instead of the accordionPanel itself. Therefore, I use [Primefaces Selectors](https://primefaces.github.io/primefaces/8_0/#/core/searchexpression?id=primefaces-selectors-pfs).